# In Angular Spartacus, cart item is not available on page load

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

In Spartacus I am trying to display an cart item in the HTML. On page load the item is not displayed but when I refresh the page the item is displayed. I am calling the this.activeCartService.getActive();
in ngOnit().  Here is a snippet of my code. Why is the cart item not available on page load but its available on page refresh? Am I missing anything?
Here is a snippet of my code.

I am using the this.cart$ = this.activeCartService.getActive(); and displaying the cart as

`

```
<div *ngIf="cart$ | async as cart">
 <div>{{cart.deliveryMode?.name}}</div>
</div>`
```

`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cart$ = this.activeCartService.getActive();
    this.cart$.subscribe((cart: Cart) => {
      console.log('cart', cart);
      this.items = cart.entries;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I have the same issue. I have a call to createPaymentDetails and I can see the payment details added in backoffice but my activeCart is stale. only available if I refresh the page. I thought the framework would take care for reloading the cart if a modification to the cart occured

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work using this.activeCartService.reloadActiveCart();